# Error 204 when trying to connect to SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm not able to connect to my SignalR Hub in a ASP.NET Core 2.0.3 application running under Windows 7.
I'm using SignalR 1.0.0-alpha1-final from NuGet as server and the signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.min.js as JavaScript client.

Here is my hub:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyHub: Hub
    {
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} joined");
        }

        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId}: {message}");
        }    
    }
}
```

Configure in startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<MyHub>("hubs");
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

and in a test page:

```
let transportType = signalR.TransportType[getParameterByName('transport')] || signalR.TransportType.WebSockets;
let http = new signalR.HttpConnection(`http://${document.location.host}/hubs`, { transport: transportType });
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection(http);
```

but when this code executes I get an error 204 from the server.

### UPDATE

Based upon the answer of @Gabriel Luci, here the working code:

```
let transportType = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling;
let http = new signalR.HttpConnection(`http://${document.location.host}/hubs`, { transport: transportType });
let connection = new signalR.HubConnection(http);

connection.start();

connection.on('Send', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});

...
connection.invoke('Echo', "Hello ");
```

Comment: Status code 204 isn't an error.

Comment: In the browser console I read: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:51278/hubs?id=c9d62f69-8dac-408b-ac7a-10521eefd30f' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 204" Error: Failed to start the connection. undefined

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue raised in GitHub for that: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1028

Apparently WebSockets doesn't work in IIS and IIS Express. You need to use long-polling. There's a snippet of sample code in that issue:

```
let connection = new HubConnection("someurl", { transport: signalR.TransportType.LongPolling });
connection.start().then(() => {});
```

Comment: It's true I had to use LongPolling (argh...) but the code didn't work. I had to add also a HttpConnection. Should I create a new answer to show the working code or post it in a comment here?

Comment: You could just edit your question and add your code to the bottom. Up to you.

Comment: This is absolutely unbelievable. I'm running in VS2017, and sure enough, couldn't get this to work without changing the transport type. Why in the world does IIS Express not support WebSockets, even in VS2017? Seriously, Microsoft?

Comment: Oh. So, just for anyone stumbling upon this, websocket support requires IIS Express 8.0+ *and* Windows 8+ or Windows Server 2012+. So, if you're developing local on a Windows 7 machine (as I am), you can't test websockets, as there's literally not OS-level support, regardless of what version of IIS Express you're running.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have to remove allow any origin and replace it with WithOrigins and AllowCredentials

```
 options.AddPolicy("policy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8081");
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowCredentials();

            });
```

Comment: I was missing `builder.AllowCredentials();`